# Showing a function is well-defined: If we assume $a=b$, doesn't it follow that $f(a)=f(b)$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

When attempting to prove a function $f: A \to B$ is well-defined, we usually start with supposing for $a,b \in A$ that $a=b$. Then we try to show that $f(a)=f(b)$.

But if we assume $a=b$, doesn't it follow that $f(a)=f(b)$ since $a=b$.

Isn't it like saying $f(a)=f(a)$ if we assume $a=b$?

Comment: But $f(a)=f(a)$ only if $f$ is a well defined function, which is exactly what you are trying to check.

Comment: No, for example define the "function" $f$ (which takes reals as inputs) as 

$$
f(x):=
\begin{cases}
x&\mbox{if}\;\;x\geqslant1 \\ 2x&\mbox{if}\;\;x\leqslant1
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: If $f$ is a well-defined function then $a=b$ implies $f(a)=f(b)$. But it's possible to write something that *looks* like a function definition, but actually doesn't define a function at all, like C.I.J.'s comment above -- it's in these cases where you have to check that $a=b$ really does imply that $f(a)=f(b)$.

Comment: Hint: Think square roots.

Comment: Timothy Gowers has written a great blog post about this issue [here](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/why-arent-all-functions-well-defined/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term 'well-defined' doesn't really mean anything: something either is a function or it isn't. The problem is that you can write stuff that *looks* like it's the definition of a function, but it might or might not be. In the cases where it is, we say the function is 'well-defined'.

For example, suppose we defined $f : \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ by letting $f(x)=y$ such that $y^2=x$. It is then possible that $f(1)=1$ or that $f(1)=-1$. What this really means is that this statement doesn't define a function: this $f$ thing that we just 'defined' doesn't actually exist, so we can't have defined it at all! The way we convey this situation is just to say that $f$ is not 'well-defined'.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the function $f$ is defined. If we have the function

$$f: \mathbb{Q^*} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$$

defined by

$$f\Big(\frac{a}{b}\Big) = \frac{\max(a,b)}{\min(a,b)}$$

If we have the pre-images $x_1 = \frac{-1}{2}$ and $x_2 = \frac{1}{-2}$, then, although $x_1 = x_2$, we deduce that

$$f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$$

Again, it depends on the function; so if a relation is being proposed to be a function, one must always check to see if the relation is well-defined or unambiguous.

Comment: What is the set $\mathbf Q^*$?

Comment: It is the set of rational numbers excluding the number 0.

Answer (score 1):

Using the notation $f(a)$ for something that is potentially not well-defined is asking for trouble; you're implicitly assuming that there's a unique value $f(a)$ assigned to each $a$.

An example: Suppose $f$ is the "function" consisting of ordered pairs $\{(x, y) : x = y^2\}$. Then we have ordered pairs $(4, 2)$ and $(4, -2)$ in our relation. Does it make sense to talk about $f(4)$?